# Is there a closed form exists for finding nth bitwise xor sum in an array?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let **A** be an array of **k** numbers (0-based indexing) such that the $n^{th}$ **bitwise xor sum** of **i** is the $(n-1)^{th}$ *bitwise xor sum* of numbers starting from $i^{th}$ number till end of array.

for example,

if A = [1,2,3,4,5, ..., k elements] and if $S^{xy}$ denotes $x^{th}$ bitwise xor sum at yth position then,

$$S^{x0} = S^{(x-1)0} \newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}S^{(x-1)1}\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}S^{(x-1)2}...\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}S^{(x-1)k}$$

It can be easily solved recursively, however, I am curious if a closed form exists for this problem such that I can find the nth sum of ith number in constant time.

Comment: If $A$ is an array that can contain an arbitrary set of numbers, you obviously need to look at every number involved in the sum, so the time will be O(k) in the worst case regardless of what you do.

Comment: O(k) is fine. Problem is if I am asked to find some nth result k number of times, then it will be O(k*k) which is very high is k is high.

Comment: If you're operating on the same array, you can compute all of these sums in O(k) time and O(k) space in one pass. Then, retrieve the relevant result in O(1) time (if we pretend array accesses are constant time).

Comment: yes, it is operating on the same array for every nth sum asked.